# Combine a variable and a string for naming a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, variables, pandas-loc

I have a dataframe with several column which have similar names, something like col_1, col_2, col_3.

I am trying to create a for loop to go over the 3 columns and want to use .loc inside the loop to slice the dataframe.

Something like this:

```
vars = [1, 2, 3]

for i in vars:
    df.loc[:, ('col_'+ i):]
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using f-strings?

```py
vars = [1, 2, 3]

for i in vars:
    df.loc[:, f'col_{i}']
```

Comment: ... which would make this a very basic Python question. Reminds me of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413387/why-is-there-such-a-large-quantity-of-beginner-python-questions-that-concern-pan).